# Why my shared video on facebook not exactly show the exact width and height of video using open graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, flash-builder, meta, facebook-opengraph

Hi i got a little problem when i shared video on facebook using Open Graph API it's fine everything is playing but i can't see the video controls and the width and height of video is not exactly fit to the width and height i've set at the meta tags. this is my meta:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image_url"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="sample"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/> 
<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://www.tefltv.com/embed/qDqVGrrzDUQ"/>
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.tefltv.com/embed/qDqVGrrzDUQ"/>
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html"/>
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640"/>
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360"/>
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.tefltv.com/tefltv_fl_video_player/tefltv_video_player.swf?source=https://www.tefltv.com/videos/tefltv.flv&autoplay=true"/>
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.tefltv.com/tefltv_fl_video_player/tefltv_video_player.swf?source=https://www.tefltv.com/videos/tefltv.flv&autoplay=true"/>
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640"/>
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have one meta wrong :

> `<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>`

It must be :

> `<meta property="og:type" content="video"/>`

or, if the video is a movie (with actors, etc ...) :

> `<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>`

Read this for more information : http://ogp.me/#type_video